# Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {category, chart, date, source})

Tags: reactjs

I'm encountering an error when running my **React** application. I have two files, `server.js` and `app.jsx` 
**When I execute `app.jsx`, I get the following error:**

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object
> with keys {category, chart, date, source}). If you meant to render a
> collection of children, use an array instead.

Can anyone help me understand and resolve this issue?

**server.js:**

```
    const express = require("express");
    const axios = require("axios");
    const cors = require("cors");
    require("dotenv").config();

    const PORT = 8080;

    const app = express();
    app.use(cors());

    app.get("/", (request, response) => {
        response.json("Its working!!!");
    });

    app.get("/charts", async (request, response) => {

      const chart_api = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://billboard-api2.p.rapidapi.com/billboard-global-200',
        params: {
           date: '2020-09-26',
           range: '1-10'
        },
        headers: {
          'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'xxx',
          'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'billboard-api2.p.rapidapi.com'
        }
      };

        //retrieve data
        const answer = await axios(chart_api);

        const chartData = {

          category: answer.data.info,
        };
    
        response.json(chartData);
    })

    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`App is running PORT ${PORT}`));
```

**app.jsx:**

```
    import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import './App.css';

    function App() {
      const [chartData, setChartData] = useState(null);

      useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
          try {
           const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/charts');
            setChartData(response.data);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
          }
        }

        fetchData();
      }, []);

      return (
       <div>
          {chartData && (
            <>
              <h1>Category: {chartData.category}</h1>
              <h1>Chart: {chartData.chart}</h1>
              <h1>Date: {chartData.date}</h1>
              <h1>Source: {chartData.source}</h1>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

When attempting to make modifications to my code using the snippet below, I've encountered an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: chartData is null

```js
    <div>
      {chartData.map((data, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <h1>Category: {data.category}</h1>
          <h1>Chart: {data.chart}</h1>
          <h1>Date: {data.date}</h1>
          <h1>Source: {data.source}</h1>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```

Comment: You can set an empty array for default state ==> **const [chartData, setChartData] = useState([]); **. This fixes the null issue and shows the data after the response is returned if the response is an array.

Answer (score 0):

When your React component mounts, the initial state will be `null` and only after the `useEffect` has successfully done the request you will have the data needed. What you can do is to add a loader to the component when the state is `null`. Keep in mind however, that you should also decide what you do
in case of a fetch error in that `try/catch`. Simple log will not be enough for the user experience.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/charts');
        setChartData(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  // can be a nice spinning loader or whatever you decide
  if(!chartData) {
    return "Loading...";
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {chartData && (
        <>
          <h1>Category: {chartData.category}</h1>
          <h1>Chart: {chartData.chart}</h1>
          <h1>Date: {chartData.date}</h1>
          <h1>Source: {chartData.source}</h1>
        </>
       )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```